# get top left position of cursor inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do is place a drop down just below cursor

I have textarea and when I'm typing something or clicking in textarea anywhere I need its top absolute position so that I can give same position to my ul li element

What I've done yet now is

```
var cursorPosition = $('#PostContent').prop("selectionStart");
            console.log(cursorPosition);
```

but its returning its text count position not height position
is there any way to get height position of cursor

Answer (score 0):

clientX - boundingClientRact from the Textare

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getBoundingClientRect is not a function(…)

Comment: than use the .position()

Answer (score 0):

this may help...

let your textarea id be 'txtarea'

```
var el=document.getElementById("txtarea");
console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect());
```

getBoundingClientRect() will return an object that has width,height,left,top,right and bottom information of that element

reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect